# How to change p-checkbox css style?

Tags: html, css, primeng

I'm using   for primeng. I want to change the style of the 
from [image]   to [image]

this is my code :

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-right: 1px;">
                                            <div class="col-md-8" style="padding: 1px;">
                                                <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="rowData.isValidPJ" binary="true" name="isValidPJ"  value="val1" 
                                                            (onChange)="OnCheckboxSelect(rowData, $event);compareDataChange(rowData)"
                                                            [disabled]="rowData.pjrAreValidated || mode  === 'READ'" >

                                                        </p-checkbox>                                                 
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

any help ?thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean convert checkbox to switch?

Comment: @NishargShah yes